# cross domain json data rejected in django tastypie

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have used django-tastypie using GET,POST,PUT,DELETE methods , they are working smoothly when   both client and server are from  same domain but if I make a request from different domain nothing happened at all.

Any clue?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    slug=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

resources.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS  
from myapp.models import Entry


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        filtering = {
        'username': ALL,
        }


class EntryResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
    queryset = Entry.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'entry'
    authorization = Authorization()
    filtering = {
        'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        'pub_date': ['exact', 'lt', 'lte', 'gte', 'gt'],
        }
```

urls.py

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from tastypie.api import Api
from myapp.resources import EntryResource, UserResource

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(EntryResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# The normal jazz here...
     (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
     (r'^basic/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'todos/test.html'})
)
```

And template file is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var data = JSON.stringify({
      "body": "This will prbbly be my lst edited  post.",
      "pub_date": "2011-05-22T00:46:38",
       "slug": "another-post",
      "title": "Another Post",

     });
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/1/?format=json",
        type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success:function(data) { 
            alert(data);
            },
        error : function(data){
            alert('error')
            },  
        })
  }) 

 </script>
    </head>
    <body>
body content goes here 
    </body>
</html>
```

now when i run http://localhost:8000/basic it working perfectly for CRUD

later i installed apache server and copied that basic.html. When I run http://localhost:81/basic.html then json data are not accepted by server. I have run both apache and python server parallelly.

Comment: You want clue, could you give us any details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set your client and your server to do cross domain ajax.

In jquery, you would do set `crossDomain : true` in your `$.ajax()` call
(see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

On the server side, you will need to set a couple of accept headers
http://enable-cors.org/

You can find out more about cross domain request by looking up the CORS specification:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: Can you please tell where to hook that accept headers in django.

Comment: You can do this in the django middleware. Here is a good example: https://gist.github.com/1369619

Comment: And here is how the middleware layer works - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/